# Property variable in list TypeScript - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have model category

```
export class CategoryModel {


public id: number;
public name: string;
public description: string;
public image: string;
public products?: ProductModel[];


constructor(id: number, name: string, desciption: string, image: string, products: ProductModel[]) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = desciption;
    this.image = image;
    this.products = products;
 }
}
```

And in component I have property `school:CategoryModel` and   `heroes: CategoryModel[];`

And I want fill my list with property like this.         `this.heroes.push(this.school)` and I have this error :

> ERROR TypeError: _this.heroes.push is not a function

Comment: missing text tho:), what is this error ?

Comment: This ERROR TypeError: _this.heroes.push is not a function

Comment: add code that contains push statement

Comment: are you initialized it ? (heroes: CategoryModel[] = [];)

Comment: This is not work for me. I do not know way.

Comment: could you try simply `heroes: any = []` @LeeJi ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
heroes: CategoryModel[] = [] // Assign heroes to empty array
this.heroes.push(new CategoryModel(1, 'Name', 'Description', 'Image'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize it to an empty array like:

```
heroes: CategoryModel[] = [];
// (else heroes: any = [];  works also)
```

and you do not need the constructor tho

```
export class CategoryModel {


public id: number;
public name: string;
public description: string;
public image: string;
public products?: ProductModel[];

}
```